# AMD Drivers for Xubuntu 16.04 (Xenial)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card

The last couple of weeks i've been using Xubuntu Xenial instead of Windows and i definitely like it more than Windows by now. The only problem is that most games are working but some aren't. I don't need any kind of help with wine or whatever, i don't have AMD drivers available for my OS.

I've read a lot online about third party drivers etc. but i can't find the drivers and how to use them for my video card and OS.

Specs:
XUbuntu 16.04 Xenial
Video card (copied from lspci)

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Madison [Mobility Radeon HD 5650/5750 / 6530M/6550M]
```

Thanks in advance,
Martijn

Comment: [g:amd drivers ubuntu](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-and-newer-on-amd-graphics

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know that there is no support for this card. 
the solution is to downgrade to lower version of the Ubutntu or Xubuntu as well. 
or use the open source of this driver. I've read that the open source is not that much good too. 
so just give it a try, everything is written here in how to install it https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/gpu-635

in this link https://community.amd.com/thread/230220 
one guy has solve this issue but I don't really understand his way because he redirected me to another site, you can try also.
Good luck my friend.